# Intersection of a 2D segment with a rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, intersection, segment

I using C# and XNA. I need an algorithm in any language to obtain the border intersection point(s) of a rectangle with a 2d segment.

I've been looking for an answer for my question for over 3 hours already and couldn't find a solution that works.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an example for a line segment intersection with an aabb box [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746274/line-intersection-with-aabb-rectangle).

Or the same question as your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99353/how-to-test-if-a-line-segment-intersects-an-axis-aligned-rectange-in-2d)