# Detect if two polygons have an area in common

Tags: android, geometry, collision-detection, google-maps-android-api-2, polygons

I need to know if some part of a `Polygon` is being shown on screen. I have two `ArrayList`s of `LatLng`, one containing the list of points forming the `Polygon`, and the second one containing the four corners of the screen.

This is my code:

```
protected boolean doPolygonsHaveAnyCoincidingArea(ArrayList<LatLng> polygon1, final ArrayList<LatLng> polygon2) {
    for (LatLng point : polygon1) {
        if (isPointInsidePolygon(point, polygon2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (LatLng point : polygon2) {
        if (isPointInsidePolygon(point, polygon1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isPointInsidePolygon(final LatLng tap, final ArrayList<LatLng> vertices) {      
    int intersectCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < vertices.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (rayCastIntersect(tap, vertices.get(j), vertices.get(j + 1))) {
            intersectCount++;
        }
    }
    return (intersectCount % 2) == 1;
}

private boolean rayCastIntersect(final LatLng tap, final LatLng vertA, final LatLng vertB) {
    final double aY = vertA.latitude;
    final double bY = vertB.latitude;
    final double aX = vertA.longitude;
    final double bX = vertB.longitude;
    final double pY = tap.latitude;
    final double pX = tap.longitude;
    if ((aY > pY && bY > pY) || (aY < pY && bY < pY) || (aX < pX && bX < pX)) {
        return false;
    }
    final double m = (aY - bY) / (aX - bX);
    final double bee = (-aX) * m + aY;
    final double x = (pY - bee) / m;
    return x > pX;
}
```

However, I think `doPolygonsHaveAnyCoincidingArea` is slower than it could, as sometimes the common area is just a little triangle, so only one of those `isPointInsidePolygon` will return true.

Is there any faster way to determine if two polygons collide or one contains the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to check that any vertice of one polygon is inside the second (imagine two equal squares, one rotated 45 degrees).

You have to:

1. Find whether any side of polygon intersects axis-aligned rectangle (screen). Try [metamal answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99353/how-to-test-if-a-line-segment-intersects-an-axis-aligned-rectange-in-2d).
2. If not, check whether one vertice of polygon is inside the rectangle (very simple test)
3. If not, check whether one vertice of rectange is inside the polygon (use your function)

Comment: My function actually does the last 2 points. I'll check how to implement the first one. Thanks!